# representing literal characters in a \newcommand or \def

Tags: macros, tex-core, unicode

Consider this short LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\def\name{...}

\begin{document}
Hello: \name
\end{document}
```

The `\def\name` line will be generated by a program and the `...` will contain TeX required to represent a string literal whose value comes from, say a database. Think of the classic mail-merge scenario.

For example, if the data value is `Foo`, then the program can generate: `\def\name{Foo}`, but if the data value is `$x+y$`, the program will need to output something like `\def\name{\$x+y\$}` in order that `$` will not be interpreted as the switch to math mode markup command.

My question is: given a sequence of Unicode code-points, how can I algorithmically create a `\def` or `\newcommand` statement which when expanded will always result in that literal sequence of Unicode characters without any possibility of any characters being interpreted as markup command.

I imagine the procedure might depend on which packages are in use, so you can assume that the above packages are in effect - although it would be nice to have a procedure which works independently of context.

Comment: You want to detokenize the stored information, by the sound of things. Are you printing stuff in a document or writing it to a file? (I'm thinking that it's easier to alter the output, rather than the input.)

Comment: The "program" I am writing will create the LaTeX document (i.e. create a file), but, of course, the only part of the generated document which will change from run to run will be the `\def` line. Note that the program doesn't need to read a LaTeX document - it just takes a Unicode string as input and writes (say on stdout) a LaTeX document.

Comment: If you only want to print stuff out, I'd just go with `\detokenize\expandafter{\name}`. The only proviso there will be to make sure you escape any `%` characters, as they will mess up the `\def` in the first place. The alternative is I guess to set up your `\def` in a verbatim-like group, but that sounds rather tiresome.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using (pdf)tex  and utf8 input, its tricky to use the usual `\detokenize` or `\meaning` to avoid special characters as you need to preserve the characters with the 8th bit set as active so that the decoding from utf-8 works.

As you are generating the document you really don't need many special characters `$`, `&` and `%` can all be made globally catcode 12 (normal punctuation). You can use `\( \)` for math, avoid comments and use `\newcell` defined via `\let\newcell&` to separate table cells.

You need an escape character, if there is *any* character that you know does not occur (eg U+0001 hasn't got much right to appear in a normal document) then you can give that character catcode 0 and use it instead of `\`

I use a scheme like this for the generated TeX source of the pdf version MathML specification.